# Pandas: renaming Series.name

Tags: python, pandas

Given:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(name="myname")
```

When:
I want to rename it to `newname2`

Then:
why should I use `s.rename("newname2")` instead of `s.name = "newname2"` ?

Answer (score 3):

Both approaches are fine. the `rename` function has more functionality than just changing the name attribute of your `pd.Series` object, you could actually change the label of your indexes.

see more @ [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html)